# lambda syntax in scheme language

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, scheme

I am learning functional programming. A question came to my mind when I read about the lambda section  introduction about [FP](http://www.dipmat.unict.it/~barba/PROG-LANG/PROGRAMMI-TESTI/READING-MATERIAL/ShortIntroFPprog-lang.htm).

```
In Scheme the syntax for anonymous functions is the following one:

(lambda (arg1...argn) body)

...

We can now easily define the compose function

(define (compose f g)
  (lambda (x) (f (g x))))
```

I struggle to understand about `x`, it is not in the argument list of definition of `compose` function. so how is `x` passed in?

also, suppose we have function `g1` taking argument `y`, `z`, how to call `compose`? `compose (f1 g1) y z`? If so, then it takes arguments not just two functions, but also the arguments from g1. I'm very confused.

Comment: `x` is argument of resulting composition. Suppose you have functions `f1` and `g1` and argument `x1`, then you can call it like that `((compose f1 g1) x1)`.

Answer (score 3):

Since

```
(define (compose f g)
  (lambda (x) (f (g x))))
```

we have

```
             (compose + *)
```

evaluates to

```
             (lambda (x) (+ (* x))).
```

That is, in

```
 ((compose + *) 42)
```

we get

```
    ((compose + *) 42)
 => ((lambda (x) (+ (* x))) 42)
 => (+ (* 42))
 => (+ 42)
 => 42
```

Answer (score 1):

First of having a list around the name and arguments is the syntax sugar. So to understand it completely lets expand it fully:

```
(define compose
  (lambda (f g)     ; compose
    (lambda (x)     ; body
      (f (g x))))
```

First off notice that the name `compose` is given to the result of evaluation of the outer lambda expression and it becomes a two argument closure.

So when you call `(compose f2 f1)` the arguments bets bound to `f` and `g` and the body expression `(lambda (x) (f (g x)))` is evaluated. It becomes a one argument closure. You could use define here to:

```
(define special-function (compose f2 f1))
```

In order to use that function you need to call it again. Thus. `(special-function 5)` would be the same as evaluating `(f2 (f1 5))`. It's easy to see using substitution rules.

So why do this then? Well. We have functions that take one function, like `map` and instead of writing:

```
(map (lambda (x) (f2 (f1 x))) '(1 2 3 4))
```

You can write

```
(map (compose f2 f1) '(1 2 3 4))
```

Which essentially is the exact same expression a little easier.

A real world `compose` function actually takes any number of arguments and it's last argument, the function to be applied first, will decide the arity of the resulting function. Thus in racket you can do:

```
((compose add1 add1 *) 3 7)
; ==> 23
```